# Security question for a Vue/Node Spotify API app question

Tags: api, security, spotify

I'm using the Spotify Authorization Code flow as a Node backend to authorize users to reach my frontend web app which uses the spotify API. Since my frontend and backend are separated, the backend has a '/callback' endpoint which is reached after users authenticate. The '/callback' then redirects to my frontend app URL with the access_token and refresh_token as query parameters. Is it a security concern for the access_token and refresh_token to be exposed in the URL? If so, what other alternatives do I have?

My frontend app URL would look something like this:

localhost:8000/play?access_token=<some_access_token>&refresh_token=<some_refresh_token>

Answer (score 0):

If you're using HTTPS, then there's no real security concern as the tokens will be encrypted in transit. If you're not using HTTPS, then there is a potential security concern as someone could potentially steal the tokens by sniffing the traffic.